# Openfire - MUC Group Chat - "This room is not anonymous"

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire, asmack

I am using asmack to work with openfire xmpp server. I have created conference(room) and two contacts are joined to this room. But both contacts are  getting message like **this room is not anonymous** . When I googled, I got this [link](http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/38807). So as per the discussion over there I have to set room.canAnyoneDiscoverJID to false. But I dont  know how to set it in asmack

Please tell me how to set it in asmack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to set room.canAnyoneDiscoverJID (default true). The equivalent of this in smack(asmack) is muc#roomconfig_whois.

```
    Form submitForm = multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm().createAnswerForm();
                            submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
                            submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
                            submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", room);
                            submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_whois",Arrays.asList("none"));
    multiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
```